# Is dispelling nearly impossible to succeed?

Tags: magic, shadowrun-sr5

The rules for dispelling say:

> A Dispelling test is the dispeller's Counterspelling + Magic [Astral] v. spell's Force + caster's Magic (+ amount of Karma spent on quickening the spell, if any) [...] Every net hit reduces the number of hits the caster had in casting the spell.

Our mage cast a Force 10 illusion with 8 magic (6 + 2-Force focus). She had 8 hits in her spellcasting test. An enemy mage would like to dispel that illusion.

If I understood the rules correctly, that means the enemy needs at least 19 hits on their dispelling test to even start to affect the spell. The enemy mage has 6 dispelling and 6 magic, so they can't possibly hope to succeed. On top of that, the attempt will cost them the drain of the 10-Force spell.

Is my understanding of the rules right? Is Dispelling really that weak?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## It is an opposed roll

The notation of "v." denotes "versus", and means that it is an opposed test. The dispeller rolls 12 and **the caster rolls** 18. While the caster is at advantage, it is not impossible.

The notation for the interpretation you understood is: A+S[limit](threshold)

For more on roll notation, see the "Tests and Limits" section starting on page 46 of the Core Rules.

Comment: Somehow all of us had misread it lol. Thanks.